# Property 'deleteMany' of object xxx is not a function in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use deletemany in mongodb version 2.6.10? However it gives me error.

Here is my query;

```
> db.person.deleteMany(  {gallery : {$ne:"test"} } );
2017-08-08T13:50:42.580+0300 TypeError: Property 'deleteMany' of object testdb.person is not a function
```

How I can delete content with where clause?

Comment: The cause will be that your MongoDB is actually less than v3.x and you should be using [`.remove()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/reference/method/db.collection.remove/) instead. All [`.deleteMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/) actually does is "wraps" the "justOne" option as `false` by default. Which is actually also the "default" for `.remove()` just as it is. So it's just a new API correction where instead separate methods are offered as `.deleteOne()` and `.deleteMany()` to clearly state the difference. But both are actually `.remove()`.

Comment: For the record `db.version()` will tell you the actual version of the server you are connected to.

Comment: refer https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/tutorial/remove-documents/ vs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/remove-documents/

Comment: See also [How to delete documents by query efficiently in mongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014181/how-to-delete-documents-by-query-efficiently-in-mongo)

Answer (score 8):

This works for me

```
db.person.remove(  {gallery : {$ne:"test"} } );
```

Answer (score 2):

To delete some records we can use: 
`db.person.remove(  {gallery : {$ne:"test"} } );`

To delete all records from a collection:
`db.person.remove({});`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting

> collection.remove is deprecated. Use deleteOne, deleteMany, or
> bulkWrite instead. (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where
> the warning was created)

So,

```
db.person.deleteMany(  {gallery : {$ne:"test"} } );
```